# Moved from Blogger to Wordpress, however I can only see the Google 404 page

Tags: 404-error, blogger

I'm using a Namecheap domain that I redirected and set up correctly.

However when I use a proxy to view the domain, I see the coming soon page. Why can I not see the updated site?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that the DNS is still updating? I changed the nameservers to the Bluehost ones.